# Ansible with jinja template. Conditional if

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am testing my first jinja2 template but I don't understand why it returns 5: 5 , instead of   `"VarVoid": "5"`

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  user: user1
  become_user: yes
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Prueba de volcado msg con lineas
      debug:
         msg: "OK"
    - name: Prueba de volcado var con lineas
      debug:
         var: VarVoid
    - name: definiendo la extructura
      set_fact:
        salida: >-
           {%- set results = [] -%}
           {%- if (VarVoid == '') -%}
                {%- set result = { "msg": "VarVoid se encuentra Vacia" } -%}
           {%- endif -%}
           {%- if (VarVoid != '') -%}
                {%- set result = { 'var': VarVoid } -%}
           {%- endif -%}
           {{ result }}

    - name: Con plantilla.
      debug: "{{ salida }}"
```

when i launch:
`ansible-playbook test-valuenull.yml -e VarVoid=` 
return:

```
TASK [definiendo la extructura] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
[WARNING]: Using a variable for a task's 'args' is unsafe in some situations (see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/faq.html#argsplat-unsafe)

TASK [Con plantilla.] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
   "msg": "VarVoid se encuentra Vacia"
```

but if I launch
`ansible-playbook test-valuenull.yml -e VarVoid=5` 
return:

```
TASK [definiendo la extructura] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
[WARNING]: Using a variable for a task's 'args' is unsafe in some situations (see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/faq.html#argsplat-unsafe)

TASK [Con plantilla.] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "5": "5"
}
```

instead of   `"VarVoid": "5"`

How can I make it not interpret the arg var?
Where can I find documentation to understand how to use jinja2 in ansible.
What I have found at https://docs.ansible.com/ is very basic

Comment: `debug: "{{ salida }}"` gives `"msg": "Hello world!"`. The story is wrong.

Comment: To me, it returns that

Comment: What's the version of Ansible? See "ansible --version".

Comment: ansible 2.9.9
python version = 2.7.5 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:16:51) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ternary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) filter. For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        salida: "{{ (VarVoid|default('')|length > 0)|
                    ternary({'var': VarVoid},
                            {'msg': 'VarVoid se encuentra Vacia'}) }}"
    - debug:
        var: salida
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "VarVoid=5"

    "salida": {
        "var": "5"
    }
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

    "salida": {
        "msg": "VarVoid se encuentra Vacia"
    }
```

---

Problem 1.

There is no free-form of [debug](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html#debug-print-statements-during-execution). Without a [parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html#parameters) the default message is "Hello world!".

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug: "{{ salida }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "salida=5"

    "msg": "Hello world!"
```

Problem 2.

The dictionary

```yaml
result = { 'var': VarVoid }
```

can't give expected

```yaml
"VarVoid": "5"
```

Comment: but
```     - name: Prueba de volcado var
      debug:  var=VarVoid```
return 
```"VarVoid": "5"```

Comment: Thanks for your time.
Where can I find good documentation or book?